# Vertical Align different sized fonts

Tags: html, css

I built the following html list and css code trying to vertical align the contents of the li elements. "Bike" "Equipment" should not be in the same line, they should be in two lines but directly underneath. With the following code it crashes, because of the line height. But how can i align stats_box_desc vertical in the center and stats_box_figure the same way, as both have a different font size?

It should look like this:
[image]

Thanks!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/foIjd

**HTML**

```
<ul class="massp_list">
    <li>
        <span>Annual spending habits</span>
    </li>
    <li class="massp_stats_box">
        <div class="stats_box_desc">Bikes</div>
        <div class="stats_box_figure">$2,274</div>
    </li>
    <li class="massp_stats_box">
        <div class="stats_box_desc">Race Fees</div>
        <div class="stats_box_figure">$564</div>
    </li>
    <li class="massp_stats_box">
        <div class="stats_box_desc">Bike<br/>Equipment</div>
        <div class="stats_box_figure">$524</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.massp_list {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
}

.massp_list li {
  margin: 10px;
}

.massp_stats_box {
  background-color: #007cc1;
  width: 180px;
  height: 56px;
  opacity:0.9;
}

.stats_box_desc, .stats_box_figure {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  height:56px;
  line-height:56px;
}

.stats_box_desc {
  font-size: 14px;
  color:black;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.stats_box_figure {
  font-size: 38px;
  color:black;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ZTK2G/

Answer (score 1):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nGk7x/1/

```
.massp_list {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
}
.massp_list li {
    margin: 10px;
}
.massp_stats_box {
    background-color: #007cc1;
    width: 180px;
    height: 56px;
    opacity:0.9;
}
.stats_box_figure {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:56px;
    line-height:56px;
}
.stats_box_desc {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:black;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-align:right;
}
.stats_box_figure {
    font-size: 38px;
    color:black;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be great!